# Global model in application Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to create simple web-application in codeigniter.

After login I want to show user points (from MySQL) in the header/menu.

Should I create this model and load inside all of my controllers or what should I do at this moment?

Regards.

Comment: Well yes,after logging in, setup userdata with sessions and in header you will have something like `if(isset($this->session->userdata))` then show points that you get from model in controller if user is logged.

Comment: @MarkoKunić but should I get points from model inside all of my controllers or create MY_Controller?

Comment: My controller, and there you ask if there is session data, if there is, get model from function

Comment: No point to do that inside of all controllers, that is why you use MY_controller that is in core of application